# jQuery onclick delete table row

Tags: jquery

How to delete table row on click?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lolipop/DjhuY/1/).

I want to delete only row on which del link is nested, not the last row how script is doing now.

Onclick calling **`delTableRow()`** function and that function need to be changed to delete nested del link row.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTableRow(jQtable){
    jQtable.each(function(){
        var tds = '<tr>';
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function() {tds += '<td>'+$(this).html()+'</td>';});
        tds += '</tr>';
        if($('tbody', this).length > 0){$('tbody', this).append(tds);
        }else {$(this).append(tds);}
    });
}
function delTableRow(jQtable){
    jQtable.each(function(){
        $('tr:last', this).remove();
    });
}
</script>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="mans">
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><a onclick="delTableRow($('#mans'));" href="#">del</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td><a onclick="delTableRow($('#mans'));" href="#">del</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td><a onclick="delTableRow($('#mans'));" href="#">del</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 9):

remove the onclick and replace with a class (ie. class="remove"). bind the event to the table - this will give you a performance gain over having lots of event handlers and make sure that new rows added will obey this behaviour too.

```
$('table').on('click','tr a.remove',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

remove all your inline javascript and use click event.... no need to call onclick event in the attr... and this should dot he trick.. `$(this).parents('tr').remove();`

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      $('table').on('click','tr a',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
      });
 });

</script>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="mans">
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><a href="#">del</a></td>
     //---^---here remove the onclick inline function for all.. 
  </tr>
 ....
</table>
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/DjhuY/4/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td a').on('click',function(e){
   //delete code.
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().parent().remove(); // OR $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: small tip here : better thing is to get all parents and chose the td parent .. that way if the delete button is a child of a div it will still remove the td not the div ..

Comment: you seem to be not getting my point here .. what i meant is this `.parents(tr)` small and effective

Comment: @codeiz that is right too but OP is looks like new to jQuery so better not mixing him so i gave it parent .parent....let me edit it again

Comment: using parents('tr') is still dangerous - what if the table was inside another table? you would then also remove the containing tr element of the parent table - which contains the information you want to keep.

Comment: @DipeshParmar don't take it personally - this place is all about improving our skills (boy do I use it alot!) but we MUST point out where solutions are deficient - otherwise the person posting that solution will travel on in this without knowing where their code can be improved.

Comment: @IanWood i do not take it personally...and yeah right this is the place where we learn....sorry but i did not meant to harsh to you...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td a').on('click',function(){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

on the anchor tags. So if your link is a child of a td, which is a child of tr, then tr will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ian Wood mentioned, we can use .closest() which will return the first ancestor, or the closest  to our delete button, and .remove() to remove the element.

This is how we can implement it using jQuery click event instead of using JavaScript onclick.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
  });
```

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
button:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th >Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th width="1%"></th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td >SSS-001</td>
  <td >Ben</td>
  <td >25</td>
  <td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td >SSS-002</td>
  <td >Anderson</td>
  <td >47</td>
  <td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td >SSS-003</td>
  <td >Rocky</td>
  <td >32</td>
  <td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td >SSS-004</td>
  <td >Lee</td>
  <td >15</td>
  <td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
</tr>
```